# Count total number of lines in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, count, lines-of-code

Is there any way to count the total number of lines inside a php project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux you have the wonderful 'wc' command:

```
wc -l yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, for pointing me out the solution. 

Using

    `wc -l + \`find . -name \* -print\``  

you can get the total number of lines of all files inside a folder